# Where can I find a data set with 1000 records of kidney patients?

Tags: data-request

I need a data set that can be used to predict kidney disease risk. I searched UCI repository but it contains only 400 records. Please help me.

Comment: you'll probably need to pay cms for the medicare sample, pay ahrq for hcup, or pay for some other proprietary medical claims database.  cdc publishes cause of death vital statistics, but that won't have much predictive utility (probably)

Answer (score 1):

MIMIC-III database is probably what you are looking for. Go to http://mimic.physionet.org/ for more information.